# A factorization problem involving Fibonacci and Lucas Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Consider a sequence of polynomial $\{w_n(x)|\, n\geq 0\}$ which are defined recursively by $w_n(x)=xw_{n-1}(x)+w_{n-2}(x)$. With $w_0(x)=0$ and $w_1(x)=1$, one gets the so-called [*Fibonacci polynomials*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_polynomials) $w_n(x)=F_n(x)$. With $w_0(x)=2$ and $w_1(x)=x$, one gets the *Lucas polynomials* $w_n(x)=L_n(x)$. While working on another problem, I noticed that for any odd $n$ the polynomial $F_n(z)^2-L_{2n}(z)+2$ appears to factor as $\phi_n(z)\phi_n(-z)$ for some polynomial $\phi_n(z)$ with integer coefficients. For example, when $n=1$ we have 
\begin{align*}
F_1(z)^2-L_{2}(z)+2&=1-(z^2+2)+2\\&=(1-z)(1+z)\end{align*}
and for $n=3$ we have
\begin{align*}F_3(z)^2-L_{6}(z)+2&=(z^2+1)^2-(z^6+6z^4+ 9 z^2 +2 )+2\\
&=(1+3z+z^2+z^3)(1-3z+z^2-z^3)
\end{align*}
Does anyone see how to prove this factorization property?

I have know idea how to tag this question. Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It appears that this is true only for odd $n$.  I tried $n = 2$ and $n = 4$ and while the expression factors, it doesn't factor into the form $\phi_n(z)\phi_n(-z)$.

Comment: @heropup: Indeed, that's why I restricted to odd $n$ in my question.

Comment: Oh, sorry--I missed that part!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key observation is that, for $n$ odd, $L_{2n}(x) = L_{n}(x)^2 + 2$; this is straightforward to show by induction, as a subcase of the more general identity $L_{m+n}(x) = L_{m}(x)L_{n}(x) + (-1)^{m-n}L_{m-n}(x)$.

Now, your polynomial $F_{n}(z)^2 - L_{2n}(z) + 2$ reduces to $F_{n}(z)^2 - L_{n}(z)^2 = (F_{n}(z) - L_{n}(z))(F_{n}(z) + L_{n}(z))$. Finally, since, for odd $n$, $F_{n}(z)$ is even and $L_n(z)$ is odd (again this is easy to show via induction), it follows that if you let $G_{n}(z) = F_{n}(z) - L_{n}(z)$, then your polynomial is simply $G_{n}(z)G_{n}(-z)$.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of the identity $L_{m+n}(x)=L_m(x)L_n(x)+(-1)^{m-n}L_{m-n}(x)$. That solves it!

Comment: That was quick too. Thanks.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, the identity for $L_{m+n}(x)$ above and the version in wikipedia are different. I think the one in wikipedia is the right one, try $m=2,n=1.$ Anyway, $$L_{m+n}(x) = L_m(x) L_n(x) - (-1)^n L_{m-n}(x).  $$ The part about $(-1)^n$ does appear a little peculiar in context, but it also seems to be correct. There is a difference based on the parity of $m,$ which does not come up in your original problem .