# Fibonacci polynomials and factorization redux

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I recently asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764119/a-factorization-problem-involving-fibonacci-and-lucas-polynomials) about factorizing a certain expression involving Fibonacci and Lucas polynomials. That question had a very simple and nice answer, but now I've come across another similar question which has me stumped.

**Conjecture:** *The polynomial $4- F_n(x)^4(x^2+3)$ factors as $H_n(x)H_n(-x)$ for some integer polynomial $H_n(x)$, where $F_n(x)$ is the nth Fibonacci polynomial.*

Any ideas?

(In case anybody is wondering why I care about these question, they are related to calculating the Conway polynomial of certain families of knots.)

**Edit:** As requested, here are the first few examples. Let $G_n(x)=4- F_n(x)^4(x^2+3)$. Then

- $G_1(x)=(1+x)(1-x)$
- $G_2(x)=(1+x)(1-x)(2+x^2)^2$
- $G_3(x)=(-1 - 3 x + 2 x^2 - 4 x^3 + x^4 - x^5) (-1 + 3 x + 2 x^2 + 4 x^3 + 
     x^4 + x^5)$
- $G_4(x)= (2 - 4 x + 4 x^2 - 10 x^3 + 4 x^4 - 6 x^5 + x^6 - x^7) (2 + 4 x + 
     4 x^2 + 10 x^3 + 4 x^4 + 6 x^5 + x^6 + x^7)$
- $G_5(x)=(-1 - 5 x + 6 x^2 - 20 x^3 + 11 x^4 - 21 x^5 + 6 x^6 - 8 x^7 + x^8 - 
     x^9) (-1 + 5 x + 6 x^2 + 20 x^3 + 11 x^4 + 21 x^5 + 6 x^6 + 8 x^7 +
      x^8 + x^9)$

**Edit 2:** Following Will Jagy's ideas, define a family of polynomials $H_n(x)$ by $H_0(x)=2$, $H_1(x)=-1+x$ and then $$H_{n+2}(x)=(x^2+2)H_{n+1}(x)-H_n(x)+(-1)^n(6+2x^2)$$ for $n\geq 0$. Computations show that $$H_n(x)H_n(-x)=G_n(x)$$ for $n\leq 20$. What remains is to prove that this is a valid formula in general.

Comment: Could you write the first few examples (small $n$) please?

Comment: @WillJagy: done.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting a crown replaced in an hour...meanwhile, it would not be at all surprising if you got a new recurrence for the factor with highest degree term coefficient +1. call it $H_1(x) = x+1,$ $H_2(x) = (x^2 + 2)(x+1),$ then $H_3(x) = x^5 + x^4 + 4 x^3 + 2 x^2 + 3 x - 1$ hope I typed properly

Comment: Yeah, my $H_{n+1}(x)$ is pretty close to $(x^2 + 2) H_n(x).$ We expect a two term recurrence, which does not quite come off, but some types of problems do allow recurrences with an extra constant term, for example. Since this does not quite work, i will need to look at it later if you have not solved it yet.

Comment: Alright, the error in the approximate two term recurrence $$  H_{n+2}(x) = (x^2 + 2)H_{n+1}(x) + H_n(x) + ERROR_{n+2}(x) $$ already seems to have its own little law with some $\pm 1$ varying term to term. So, this is pretty close.

Comment: So, I got a little something, but I have no idea how any of this relates to the Fibonacci polynomial expression you typed.

Comment: @WillJagy: Yes, your idea yields fruit. I edited my question to incorporate the resulting explicit polynomials $H_n(x)$.

Comment: Grumpy, I checked carefully, your typing of $4- F_n^4(x^2+3)$ is not the same as your $G_n(x).$ From the factorizations, you actually used $$ G_n(x) = 4 - (x^2 + 3) F_n^4(x).  $$ In particular, this way the degrees of the two sides agree.

Comment: @WillJagy: see my comment below. I will edit to make it crystal clear!

Answer (score 2):

This looks a little better, $H_1(x) = 1 + x, \; H_2(x) = 2 + 2x + x^2 + x^3, \; H_3(x) = -1 + 3 x + 2 x^2 + 4 x^3 + x^4 + x^5, $ then
$$   H_{n+2}(x) = (2+ x^2) H_{n+1}(x) - H_n(x) + OTHERERROR_{n+2}(x),   $$
where this way the error stays quadratic, by hand calculations the first three error terms come out
$$ -4 + x^2, \; 6 + 2 x^2, \; -6 - 2 x^2... $$

Comment: Back from the dentist?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, right. It went well, I was just annoyed at having to do it in the first place. Anyway, if this sequence keeps giveng error $A x^2 + B$ for a few more terms, i would say you have a winner, fixed degree being officially "small" in this setting, whereupon you just see if the coefficients $A,B$ have a nice recurrence.

Comment: Looks like you're on to something. $\mathrm{OTHERERROR}_k$ continues to oscillate between $6+2x^2$ and $-(6+2x^2)$ for the next several values I checked.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip , I checked carefully, your typing of $4- F_n^4(x^2+3)$ is not the same as your $G_n(x).$ From the factorizations, you actually used $$ G_n(x) = 4 - (x^2 + 3) F_n^4(x).  $$ In particular, this way the degrees of the two sides agree.

Comment: It's a matter of ambiguous notation. In my original expression, I meant $F_n$ to stand for the Fibonacci polynomial, so for me the two expressions are the same. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: Using generating functions, I've managed to get a formula for $H_n(x)$ but it is not very pretty. $H_n=(6+2x^2)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^{n-k}x^{-1}F_{2k+2}\right)+2x^{-1}F_{2n+2}+(-2x^2+x-5)x^{-1}F_{2n}$.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, meanwhile, taking $W_n(x) = F_{4n}(x),$  we get $$  W_{n+2}(x) = (x^4 + 4 x^2 + 2) W_{n+1}(x) - W_n(x), $$ and i expect the analogous thing for Lucas...there is still quite a way to go to get a recurrence for $P_n(x) = F_n^4(x).$

Comment: I added an answer which includes the derivation of a closed formula for $H_n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I think all this recurrence relation stuff is a red herring. Instead, it seems to be more relevant that the polynomials $F_n(x)$ form a basis for $\mathbb Z[x]$, and that one can multiply them according to the formula:
$$F_n(x)F_m(x)=F_{n+m-1}(x)-F_{n+m-3}(x)+\cdots\pm F_{|n-m|+1}(x)$$
where the signs alternate. This can be proven by considering the formula $F_n=\frac{\alpha^n-\bar{\alpha}^n}{\alpha-\bar{\alpha}}$. After playing around, I came up with the following pretty simple looking conjecture, which can be easily verified by computer for low values of $n$. This would completely solve the original problem.

**Conjecture:** For all $n\geq 1$, $$4-(F_3(x)+2F_1(x))F_n(x)^4=\left(F_1(x)+F_3(x)-F_5(x)+\cdots+(-1)^nF_{2n-1}(x)\right)^2-F_{2n}(x)^2.$$ The signs of $F_1$ and $F_3$ are both positive, but they alternate after that.

**Original answer:** I wanted to record here the derivation of a closed formula for the recursively defined $H_n(x)$ which ultimately expresses it in terms of Fibonacci polynomials.

Letting $H_0=2, H_1=-1+x$ and $H_n=(x^2+2)H_{n-1}-H_{n-2}+(-1)^n(6+2x^2$, form the generating function $\varphi(x,y)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n(x)y^n$. Then
\begin{align*}
(x^2+2)y\varphi(x,y)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x^2+2)H_{n-1}y^n\\
-y^2\varphi(x,y)&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty -H_{n-2}y^n\\
\frac{y^2(6+2x)}{1+y}&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n(6+2x^2)y^n
\end{align*}
Adding these all up, we get
$$(x^2+2)y\varphi(x,y)-y^2\varphi(x,y)+\frac{y^2(6+2x)}{1+y}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty H_ny^n+(x^2+2)(2y)$$
Now use that  $\sum_{n=2}^\infty H_ny^n=\varphi(x,y)-(-1+x)y-2$ and solve for $\varphi(x,y)$ to get the generating function:
$$\varphi(x,y)=\frac{1}{y^2-(x^2+2)y+1}\left(2+(-2x^2+x-5)y+\frac{y^2(6+2x)}{1+y}\right)$$
The roots of $y^2-(x^2+2)y+1$ as a polynomial in $y$ are $\zeta=\frac{x^2+2+x\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}$ and $\overline{\zeta}=\frac{x^2+2-x\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}$. Notice $\zeta\overline{\zeta}=1$. Using partial fractions, one sees that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{y^2-(x^2+2)y+1}&=\frac{1}{\zeta-\overline{\zeta}}\left(\frac{1}{y-\zeta}-\frac{1}{y-\overline{\zeta}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\zeta-\overline{\zeta}}\left(\frac{-\overline{\zeta}}{1-y\overline{\zeta}}+\frac{\zeta}{1-y\zeta}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\zeta-\overline{\zeta}}\left(-\overline{\zeta}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \overline{\zeta}^ny^n+\zeta \sum_{n=0}^\infty \zeta^ny^n\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\zeta^{n+1}-\overline{\zeta}^{n+1}}{\zeta-\overline{\zeta}}  \right)y^n
\end{align*}
Let $q_n=\left(\frac{\zeta^{n+1}-\overline{\zeta}^{n+1}}{\zeta-\overline{\zeta}} \right)$. Then $\displaystyle \frac{1}{y^2-(x^2+2)y+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty q_n y^n$. Plugging in to the earlier formula, and skipping some algebra, we get
that $H_0=2$, $H_1=2q_1+(-2x^2+x-5)q_0=-1+x$ and
$$
H_n=(6+2x^2)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^{n-k}q_k+2q_n+(-2x^2+x-5)q_{n-1}
$$
for $n\geq 2$.

Now recall that the Fibonacci polynomial $$F_n=\frac{\alpha^n-\overline{\alpha}^n}{\alpha-\overline{\alpha}}$$ where $\alpha=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}$. Note that $\overline{\alpha}+\alpha=x$ and that $\alpha^2=\zeta$. 
Then
$$q_n=\frac{\zeta^{n+1}-\overline{\zeta}^{n+1}}{\zeta-\overline{\zeta}}=\frac{\alpha^{2n}-\overline{\alpha}^{2n}}{\alpha^2-\overline{\alpha}^2}=\frac{1}{\alpha+\overline{\alpha}}\frac{\alpha^{2n}-\overline{\alpha}^{2n}}
{\alpha-\overline{\alpha}}=x^{-1}F_{2n+2}.$$

So we get
$$H_n(x)=(6+2x^2)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^{n-k}x^{-1}F_{2k+2}\right)+2x^{-1}F_{2n+2}+(-2x^2+x-5)x^{-1}F_{2n}$$
for $n\geq 2$.

It is interesting to notice that in this formula, the only odd degree terms come from the $F_{2n}$ term on the right. So we have
\begin{align*}&H_n(x)H_n(-x)=\\&\left[ (6+2x^2)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^{n-k}x^{-1}(F_{2k+2})\right)+2x^{-1}F_{2n+2}+(-2x^2-5)x^{-1}F_{2n}\right]^2-F_{2n}^2\end{align*}

Thus the original question is reduced to the following complicated identity on Fibonacci polynomials:
\begin{align*}&4-(x^2+3)F_n(x)^4=\\&\left[ (6+2x^2)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^{n-k}x^{-1}(F_{2k+2})\right)+2x^{-1}F_{2n+2}+(-2x^2-5)x^{-1}F_{2n}\right]^2-F_{2n}^2\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$F_n(x)$ satisfies a length 2 homogeneous linear recurrence with coefficients in $k = \mathbb{C}(x)$. Your guess for $H_n(x)$ satisfies a length 3 homogeneous linear recurrence again with coefficients in $k$. Similarly $H_n(-x)$ also satisfies a length 3 recurrence.

Standard results about such so called $C$-finite sequences tells us that $A_n = 4- F_n(x)^4(x^2+3) - H_n(x)H_n(-x)$ satisfies a homogeneous linear recurrence of length at most 15.  In particular if $A_n = 0$ for the first 15 values of $n$ it must be true for all values of $n$.

So since you checked this up to $n=20$ you are already done.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect that! Can you clarify where the 15 comes from?

Comment: I'm at a bar now so vague answer with no latex(sorry): 15 = 1 +5+9. 1 for the constant, 9 is 3 times 3 for the H term, 5 is for the F^4 term it's the dimension of Sym^4 of a 2 dimensional space.